# Python Pyqt5 Qlabel refreshing after button Click

Tags: python, pyqt5

I wrote a simple code in Python GUI using PYQT5 , I want to do when I click a correct button (exp. "Das" is correct), `i` increments itself by '1' and also "label1" must show new `artikel[i+1]` value.

I did i increment, but label1 could not show new string its keep old string . label1 should update itself when I incremented the `i` value

Thanks in advance

```
import pandas as pd
import xlrd as xl
from pandas import ExcelWriter
from pandas import ExcelFile
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QAction, QLineEdit, QMessageBox
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QLabel
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *


DataF=pd.read_excel("/home/emir/Masaüstü/artikel.xlsx")

print("Column headings:")
print(DataF.columns)

for q in DataF.index:
    print(DataF['artikel'][q])

for q in DataF.index:
    print(DataF['Wort'][q])

for q in DataF.index:
    print(DataF['Plural'][q])



class App(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'Deutsch Lern'
        self.left = 10
        self.top = 100
        self.width = 320
        self.height = 200
        self.i=0
        self.a=False

        self.initUI()
   

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)


        button = QPushButton('Der', self)
        button.setToolTip('Kontrol Et')
        button.move(20, 160)
        button.clicked.connect(self.on_click)

        button2 = QPushButton('Die', self)
        button2.setToolTip('Kontrol Et')
        button2.move(110, 160)
        button2.clicked.connect(self.on_click2)

        button3 = QPushButton('Das', self)
        button3.setToolTip('Kontrol Et')
        button3.move(200, 160)
        button3.clicked.connect(self.on_click3)

        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)

        # Create textbox

        self.label1 = QLabel(DataF['Wort'][self.i], self)

        self.label1.move(130, 80)
        #if (self.a == True):
        #    self.label2 = QLabel(DataF['Wort'][self.i], self)
        #    self.i += 1
        #    self.label2.move(13, 80)
        #   self.show()
        # I tried create new label when a=True.didn't work.


        self.show()



    @pyqtSlot()
    def on_click(self):

     if(DataF['artikel'][self.i]=="der"):
        #print(DataF['Plural'][1])
        print('dogru')
        a=True
        self.i+=1

     else:
         print("yanlış")
        


    def on_click2(self):

     if (DataF['artikel'][self.i] == "die"):

        print('dogru')
        a=True
        self.i+=1

     else:
         print("yanlış")
         
    def on_click3(self):

     if (DataF['artikel'][self.i] == "das"):

        print('dogru')
        a=True
        self.i+=1

        #self.art()
        print(self.i)
     else:
         print("yanlış")
            



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I don't see you update `label1` anywhere...?

Comment: You can see in class App(QWidget):   -----  self.label1 = QLabel(DataF['Wort'][self.i], self) ,self.label1.move(130, 80)

Comment: I tried to update with if cont. I putted an boolean value when the button turns True value if cont. will catch the boolean value and write new "i" value.But didnt work.

Comment: share your .xlsx

Comment: hi eyllanesc , I read your previous post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41819082/updating-pyqt-label?rq=1)  its very usefull but I couldn't apply my project.I attached .xlsx file https://yadi.sk/i/tZza3M-a3aa8sX

Comment: dear @eyllanesc

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED

`button3.clicked.connect(self.on_click3)`  goes to under `def on_click3(self):` and going inside  `if (DataF['artikel'][self.i] == "das"):` if that condition
 correct , it should return this `return self.label1.setText(DataF['Wort'][self.i]))` and label1  changes easily.